# Make the last item's view in SimpleCursorAdapter different?

Tags: android, view, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Is there a way to give the last item a different view than the other items using SimpleCusorAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

with SimpleCusorAdapter, you can't do it. You have to create cursor adapter and on bindView of it you can write code customize end result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a SimpleCursorAdapter as well by overriding the newView method. In that method, just check to see if you are at the last item and return a different view.

```
View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // cursor.getPosition() is zero-based
    if(cursor.getPosition() == cursor.getCount() - 1) {
        // It's the last view
    } else {
        // Something else
    }
}
```

Untested, but give it a shot.

Edit: Use newView() instead of bindView()

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out with getView(), if anyone thinks this is a bad idea, I'll mark someone else as the correct answer.